# How to store data when items passed are dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a questionnaire page that allow users to create/edit/delete questions. The problem i'm having is that since the questions are dynamic, i'm unsure how to store the responses to the questions back to the server.

One way would be to create a ResponseTable that just has 100+ columns for each question. For example, q1, q2, q2,..,etc. But, that really doesn't seem the right way to do it.

Another way could just be store each question response and have an id that refers back the the whole response.

Any suggestions on how this is suppose to be done?

Comment: need more clarification. How are the responses? what kind of questions are these(Multiple choice questions? or essays?)

Comment: @Aniket the questions are an assortment types. But their passed back to server as strings. The lengths of the string can vary from 1 to >1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: 
1. There will be multiple questionnaires
2. Questionnaires will have multiple questions

I would create several different tables:

NAME: Users
DESC: Stores user information
COLUMNS: uid int (primary key), first_name, last_name, etc...

NAME: Questionnaire
DESC: Stores information about a questionnaire.
COLUMNS: qid int (primary key), creator, date_created

NAME: Questions
DESC: Stores information about questions
COLUMNS: question_id (primary key), qid (foreign key from the Questionnaire table)

NAME: Responses
DESC: Stores information about the responses to questions
COLUMNS: response_id (primary key), question_id (foreign key from the Questions table), response_text (the actual response), user_id (foreign key from the Users table).

Let me know if you need additional help (queries to link these tables together etc...)

Comment: could you elaborate on response_text? What would that be? How exactly would i store all the responses (over 50+ questions) in 1 field?

Comment: The responses would not be stored in one field. Each response would be stored in its own row in the Responses table. Each response would be linked to its respective question in the Questions table by using the foreign key question_id.

Comment: ahh okay, so like my second suggestion?